# amazon, cognito, how to forgot password by email and also by username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In aws cognito by default you can forgot password by username. How i can do it by username and also by email? Maybe i can do it with lambda or something else. thank you in advance.

Comment: are the users created in cognito by an external directory (OIDC) or created directly within Cognito?

Comment: created directly within cognito

Comment: I would prefer the way using a Lambda function with SES. You can track the usage of this function, store the last password reset of a user to handle unnecessary sending of too many mails and also, if necessary, check, if the user is allowed to login to you application (if you have e.g. paid services or something else). I am using often a bunch of Lambdas as triggers, using Cognito with a temporarly DynamoDb in background to track misuse of the function.